# Text-based adventure in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a text-based RPG, but I've found numerous problems, like:

- being unable to go anywhere after entering the shop;
- I cannot access the "tavern" for some reason; and
- the computer just says `"buy is not defined in crossbow"`.

Code:

```
gold = int(100)
inventory = ["sword", "armor", "potion"]

print("Welcome hero")
name = input("What is your name: ")
print("Hello", name,)
# role playing program
#
# spend 30 points on strenght, health, wisdom, dexterity 
# player can spend and take points from any attribute

classic = {"Warrior",
         "Archer",
         "Mage",
         "Healer"}
print("Choose your race from", classic,)
classicChoice = input("What class do you choose: ")
print("You are now a", classicChoice,)


# library contains attribute and points
attributes = {"strenght": int("0"),
             "health": "0",
             "wisdom": "0",
             "dexterity": "0"}

pool = int(30)
choice = None
print("The Making of a Hero !!!")
print(attributes)
print("\nYou have", pool, "points to spend.")

while choice != "0":
    # list of choices
    print(
    """
    Options: 

    0 - End
    1 - Add points to an attribute
    2 - remove points from an attribute
    3 - Show attributes
    """
    )
    choice = input("Choose option: ")
    if choice == "0":
        print("\nYour hero stats are:")
        print(attributes)
    elif choice == "1":
        print("\nADD POINTS TO AN ATTRIBUTE")
        print("You have", pool, "points to spend.")
        print(
        """
        Choose an attribute:
           strenght
           health
           wisdom
           dexterity
        """
        )
        at_choice = input("Your choice: ")
        if at_choice.lower() in attributes:
            points = int(input("How many points do you want to assign: "))
            if points <= pool:
                pool -= points
                result = int(attributes[at_choice]) + points
                attributes[at_choice] = result
                print("\nPoints have been added.")
            else:
                print("\nYou do not have that many points to spend")
        else:
            print("\nThat attribute does not exist.")
    elif choice == "2":
        print("\nREMOVE POINTS FROM AN ATTRIBUTE")
        print("You have", pool, "points to spend.")
        print(
        """
        Choose an attribute:
           strenght
           health
           wisdom
           dexterity
        """
        )
        at_choice = input("Your choice: ")
        if at_choice.lower() in attributes:
            points = int(input("How many points do you want to remove: "))
            if points <= int(attributes[at_choice]):
                pool += points
                result = int(attributes[at_choice]) - points
                attributes[at_choice] = result
                print("\nPoints have been removed.")
            else:
                print("\nThere are not that many points in that attribute")
        else:
            print("\nThat attribute does not exist.")

    elif choice == "3":
        print("\n", attributes)
        print("Pool: ", pool)
    else:
        print(choice, "is not a valid option.")






print("Here is your inventory: ", inventory)
print("What do you wish to do?")
print("please input shop, tavern, forest.")
choice = input("Go to the shop, go to the tavern, go to the forest: ")

crossbow = int(50)
spell = int(35)
potion = int(35)


if choice == "shop":
      print("Welcome to the shop!")
      print("You have", gold,"gold")
      buy = input("What would you like to buy? A crossbow, a spell or a potion: ")


if buy == "crossbow":
         print("this costs 50 gold")
         answer = input("Do you want it: ")
         if answer == "yes":
             print("Thank you for coming!")
             inventory.append("crossbow")
             gold = gold - crossbow
             print("Your inventory is now:")
             print(inventory)
             print("Your gold store now is: ", gold)
         if answer == "no":
             print("Thank you for coming!")

if buy == "spell":
         print("this costs 35 gold")
         answear2 = input("Do you want it: ")
         if answear2 == "yes":
             print("Thank you for coming!")
             inventory.append("spell")
             gold = gold - spell
             print("Your inventory is now:")
             print(inventory)
         if answear2 == "no":
             print("Thank you for coming!")


if buy == "potion":
         print("this costs 35 gold")
         answear3 = input("Do you want it: ")
         if answear3 == "yes":
             print("Thank you for coming!")
             inventory.append("spell")
             gold = gold - potion
             print("Your inventory is now:")
             print(inventory)
         if answear3 == "no":
             print("Thank you for coming!")



choice = input("Go to the shop, go to the tavern, go to the forest: ")
while choice != "shop" or "tavern" or "forest":
      print("Not acepted")
      print("What do you wish to do?")
      print("please input shop, tavern, forest.")
      choice = input("Go to the shop, go to the tavern, go to the forest: ")

if choice == "teavern":
    print("You enter the tavern and see a couple of drunken warriors singing, a landlord behind the bar and a dodgy figure sitting at the back of the tavern.")
    tavernChoice = input("Would you like to talk to the 'drunken warriors', to the 'inn keeper', approach the 'dodgy figure' or 'exit'")

if tavernChoice == "drunken warriors":
    print("You approach the warriors to greet them.")
    print("They notice you as you get close and become weary of your presence.")
    print("As you arrive at their table one of the warriors throughs a mug of ale at you.")
    if dexterity >= 5:
        print("You quickly dodge the mug and leave the warriors alone")
    else:
        print("You are caught off guard and take the mug to the face compleatly soaking you.")
        print("The dodgy figure leaves the tavern")
```

Answer (score 0):

The first time you ask the user where to go on line 111, what happens if they enter something besides "shop"? then the `if choice == "shop":` condition on line 119 will fail, and `buy = input("...")` will never execute. At that point, `buy` doesn't exist, so when the next conditional executes, it crashes because it can't evaluate `if buy == "crossbow"`. `buy` has no value, so you can't compare it to anything.

You need to indent all of your shop logic so that it lies inside the `if choice == "shop"` block.

```
if choice == "shop":
    print("Welcome to the shop!")
    print("You have", gold,"gold")
    buy = input("What would you like to buy? A crossbow, a spell or a potion: ")

    if buy == "crossbow":
        print("this costs 50 gold")
        #...etc
    if buy == "spell":
        print("this costs 35 gold")
```

And the same problem is present for your tavern code. Even if you don't go to the tavern, you check for `tavernChoice`. That needs to be indented as well.

```
if choice == "teavern":
    print("You enter the tavern and see a couple of drunken warriors singing, a landlord behind the bar and a dodgy figure sitting at the back of the tavern.")
    tavernChoice = input("Would you like to talk to the 'drunken warriors', to the 'inn keeper', approach the 'dodgy figure' or 'exit'")

    if tavernChoice == "drunken warriors":
        print("You approach the warriors to greet them.")
```

At this point, your program will end, but I'm guessing you want to continue to be able to explore areas. You could put everything in a `while` loop, starting with the first `input` command.

```
while True:
    print("Here is your inventory: ", inventory)
    print("What do you wish to do?")
    print("please input shop, tavern, forest.")
    choice = input("Go to the shop, go to the tavern, go to the forest: ")

    if choice == "shop":
        print("Welcome to the shop!")
        #...etc

    elif choice == "tavern":
        print("You enter the tavern...")
        #...etc

    elif choice == "forest":
        print("You enter the forest...")
        #etc

    else:
        print("Not acepted")
        print("What do you wish to do?")
        print("please input shop, tavern, forest.")
```

This is also a little cleaner than your current method, since you only have to ask the user where they're going once, instead of three times on lines 112, 165, and 170.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Kevin's answer, here is a version with redundancy squeezed out, so you can add a new place just by adding a new `def go_xyz(): ...` near the top.

```
def go_shop():
    print("Welcome to the shop!")
    #...etc

def go_tavern():
    print("You enter the tavern...")
    #...etc

def go_forest():
    print("You enter the forest...")
    #etc

places = {name[3:]:globals()[name] for name in globals() if name.startswith('go_')}
placenames = ', '.join(places)

inventory = ['book']
retry = False

while True:
    if not retry:
        print("Here is your inventory: ", inventory)
    else:
        print("I do not know that place")
    print("Where do you wish to go?")
    print("Possible places: ", placenames, '.')
    choice = input("? ")
    try:
        places[choice]()
        retry = False
    except KeyError:
        retry = True
```